# How I can Open Keyboard on Screen in Mac OS using Swift Code

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

How I can Open keyboard on screen programmatically  using Swift code  for Mac OS app

I tried that by using the apple script as described in (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/409790/shortcut-to-toggle-keyboardviewer-with-applescript-on-big-sur)   but it failed when running  from my App but it worked when running form   script Editor apple utility

**My Mac Os Version  11.5.2**

the error details

error: NSAppleScriptErrorMessage = "System Preferences got an error: Application isn\U2019t running.";

I added the following in  entitlements file
com.apple.preference.keyboard

com.apple.Preferences

Comment: How do you run what from which app? How did you add `com.apple.preference.keyboard` and `com.apple.Preferences`?

Comment: I run the Apple Script from My application using Swift Code -- The Application has file with extension  entitlements type , which i added com.apple.preference.keyboard - com.apple.Preferences

Comment: Post a [mre] please.